# Oracle PL/SQL Developer: Return %RowType from Package Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

i'm kind of new to Oracle Pl\SQL. I was just trying to create a simple Package with a procedure that returns a set of object id's; the code is as follows:

```
--Package Spec
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST IS
--GET OBJECT ID'S FROM CONTROL TABLE
   PROCEDURE get_object_id_control(p_obj_id OUT abc_table%ROWTYPE);
END;

--Package Body
PROCEDURE get_object_id_control(p_obj_id OUT abc_table%ROWTYPE) AS
  BEGIN
    SELECT object_id
      INTO p_obj_id
      FROM abc_table
     WHERE fec_proc IS NULL;     
  END;
```

I get Error: PL/SQL: ORA-00913: too many values. Is this the correct way for returning multiple values of same data type, or is there a better approach. Thanks in advance.

Comment: btw `table%rowtype` defines a PL/SQL record matching the table definition, i.e. a single record with a field for each column. It looks like you actually want an array of `abc_table.object_id%type` (or just a reusable table-of-integer of some sort), not a record of `abc_table%rowtype`.

Comment: Exactly @William Robertson. My first approach was to have an array of abc_table.object_id%type; not a record of abc_table%rowtype. That's why I used @Matthew McPeak approach, which I believe creates sort of an array of NUMBER Type: `TYPE id_table_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to GurV's answer (since he beat me by like 30 seconds...), you can use a PL/SQL object type as well.  You do not need the `CREATE TYPE` statement if you don't need to reference the type in SQL.

```
--Package Spec
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST AS
  TYPE id_table_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
--GET OBJECT ID'S FROM CONTROL TABLE
   PROCEDURE get_object_id_control(p_obj_id_list OUT id_table_type);
END;

--Package Body
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST AS
   PROCEDURE get_object_id_control(p_obj_id_list OUT id_table_type) AS
  BEGIN
    SELECT object_id 
      BULK COLLECT INTO p_obj_id_list
      FROM abc_table
     WHERE fec_proc IS NULL;
  END;
END;
```

To use it:

```
DECLARE
  l_id_list   test.id_table_type;
BEGIN
  test.get_object_id_control (p_obj_id_list => l_id_list);

  FOR i IN l_id_list.FIRST .. l_id_list.LAST LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_id_list (i));
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the shorter version and worked just fine. Now, is there a way to iterate and output the values inside p_obj_id_list i.e. dbms_output.put_line(p_obj_id_list) using this approach?

Comment: Yes, pretty much the same way as if you'd used an object type, as in GurV's answer.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom table type and set the out parameter of the procedure to that type.

```
CREATE TABLE ABC_TABLE(ID varchar2(100));

create or replace type abc_tab is table of varchar2(100);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST IS
   PROCEDURE get_object_id_control(p_obj_id OUT abc_tab);
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST IS
  PROCEDURE get_object_id_control(p_obj_id OUT abc_tab) AS
  BEGIN
    SELECT id
      bulk collect INTO p_obj_id
      FROM abc_table;   
  END;
END;
/
```

Then you can call it like so:

```
declare
  v abc_tab;
begin
  TEST.get_object_id_control(p_obj_id => v);
  for i in v.first..v.last loop
    dbms_output.put_line(v(i));
  end loop;
end;
/
```